# Python/SQL - Connecting to different databases

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm not a developer at all, but I've been asked to code a simple script to connect to multiple remote databases, and to input thir data into one local database.

After managing to do it one by one, and by placing the login and password in the code, I need to do it automatically and with a local DB containing the different options.

I managed to connect to the local DB and get the data I need, but I can't connect using the dictionary name.

Here is my code :

```
import mysql.connector
import calendar
import time
import datetime
import glob
import sys
import os

master_conn = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'zzzzzz',
  'host': 'localhost',
  'database': 'all_clients_info'
}

connector = mysql.connector.connect(**master_conn)
cursor = connector.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("select * from infos;")
counter = 0
for row in cursor:
  remote_ip = row['remote_ip']
  remote_username = row['db_username']
  remote_pwd = row['db_pwd']
  remote_db = row['db_name']
  v = {}
  v["user"]= remote_username
  v["password"]= remote_pwd
  v["host"]= remote_ip
  v["database"]= remote_db
  v_name = "newdb"+str(counter)
  locals()[v_name] = v
  print(v_name)
  counter += 1
```

The output of `print(v_name)` gives me :

```
newdb0
newdb1
newdb2
```

What I need, is that when I do `print(v_name)`, it gives me the actual content of the dictionary, as if I typed

```
print(newdb0)
  {'user': '**xxx**', 'password': '**xxx**', 'host': '**xxx**', 'database': '**xxx**'}
print(newdb1)
  {'user': '**xxx**', 'password': '**xxx**', 'host': '**xxx**', 'database': '**xxx**'}
print(newdb2)
  {'user': '**xxx**', 'password': '**xxx**', 'host': '**xxx**', 'database': '**xxx**'}
```

I may not use the good code, so please help me and feel free to correct me if needed.

Much appreciated, thanks !

## Update

Thanks to Klaus.D, I was just dumb with the print part.
But there is a problem, as the following code is :

```
connector = mysql.connector.connect(**v)
```

The **v is is said to be :

```
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Comment: Like `print(v)`?

Comment: For the ```print(v)``` part it works, thanks ! But know I face another problem, which is the fact that i can't use ```connector = mysql.connector.connect(**v)``` becausde it is referenced as ``` ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists```.